# How to note several transformations at once like 2x-4=0 | +4; :2

Tags: notation

I have a long equation in a TeX document and want to show help the reader to see clearly the transformations.
On the other hand I do not want to repeat the equation for every little perhaps trivial step. 
Is there a common way to typeset a list of operations?

Minimal working example: Should I write
\begin{align}
2x-4&=0 \quad | +4;\, :2\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad\quad\quad x&=2
\end{align}

or better

\begin{align}
2x-4&=0 \quad | +4\, |\, :2\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad\quad\quad x&=2
\end{align}

or something different? 
Is it obvious to read this from left to right?

Comment: How about adding some text in between? Like "we add four on both sides and divide the resulting equation by two to obtain..." -- this has also the advantage that you don't end up with a long equation array which doesn't look nice and makes TeX produces unwanted white spaces.

Comment: Neither of these make sense to me

Comment: Either add inline explanation or a sentence if necessary

Comment: I will go with @James solution for now, but keep the question open, because I am still interested in the answer to the question.